# How do I correct a python function that does not allow me to enter variables?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to get this function written for class and am stuck on the input part. When I run it, it comes back blank. I'm still new to function and I would like to get feedback on my code.

Here is the code:

```
def sum_sides(side1,side2,side3,side4):

    side1=0
    side2=0`
    side3=0
    side4=0
    side1=int(input("Enter side 1"))
    side2=int(input("Enter side 2"))
    side3=int(input("Enter side 3"))
    side4=int(input("Enter side 4"))
    sum=side1+side2+side3+side4
    return ()
    if (x %4==0):
        print("Forms a square with perimeter of ",sum)
    elif (x %2==0):
        print("Forms a rectangle with perimeter of ",sum)
    else:
        print("Does not form a rectangle or square.")
```

What I want the output to read:
Example 1:

```
Enter side 1
> 5
Enter side 2
> 3
Enter side 3
> 3
Enter side 4
> 5
Forms a rectangle with perimeter of 16
```

Look forward to reading feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: Where does `x` come from? and why are you returning in the middle of the function?

Comment: That `return` statement makes all of the subsequent code in the function irrelevant - it can never be reached.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go through the code piece by piece to explain what's going on:

```
def sum_sides(side1, side2, side3, side4):
    side1=0
    side2=0`
    side3=0
    side4=0
    side1=int(input("Enter side 1"))
    side2=int(input("Enter side 2"))
    side3=int(input("Enter side 3"))
    side4=int(input("Enter side 4"))
```

Your function starts by taking four arguments (`side1...4`), but it doesn't use the values that were passed in; instead it replaces those values, first with 0, and then with input from the user.  If you want this function to take parameters, then the input should come from outside the function; if you want this function to handle the input, then it doesn't need to take parameters.

```
    sum = side1 + side2 + side3 + side4
```

So far so good!  Now `sum` contains the sum of the four sides (the ones you got from `input()`), not the ones that were passed into your function).  Note that naming a variable `sum` is generally a bad idea because it conflicts with the name of the very useful `sum` function that's built into Python (whose job is, you guessed it, to take the sum of things).  It'd be better to name this `perimeter`, since that's what we call the sum of the sides of a shape.

```
    return ()
```

And now we're done -- we return `()` (an empty tuple) to the caller.  The value of `sum` is never used and disappears into the void.

```
    if (x % 4 == 0):
        print("Forms a square with perimeter of ",sum)
    elif (x % 2==0):
        print("Forms a rectangle with perimeter of ",sum)
    else:
        print("Does not form a rectangle or square.")
```

This code never gets executed, but if it did, it would immediately raise an error, because `x` was never defined.

Here's an example of how you could implement the part you've done so far (prompting the user for the four sides and then summing them up) in a way that would make it possible to do the next part:

```
from typing import List


def get_sides_from_user() -> List[int]:
    """Prompts the user to enter four ints,
    representing the four sides of a quadrilateral."""
    return [int(input(f"Enter side {n}: ")) for n in range(1, 5)]


def get_and_sum_sides() -> None:
    """Get sides from the user and then print interesting information."""
    # Get the four sides.
    sides = get_sides_from_user()  

    # Sum them up!
    perimeter = sum(sides)
    print(f"The perimeter is {perimeter}.")

    # Now how do we figure out whether it's a square or not?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_and_sum_sides()
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down! This makes it much easier to understand.

Comment: Nice explanation. The OP is a beginner. Adding a few links for list comprehension, f-string formatting, etc would help him understand your answer better. Just a suggestion. Happy coding <3

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
def sum_sides():
    side1=int(input("Enter side 1\n>"))
    side2=int(input("Enter side 2\n>"))
    side3=int(input("Enter side 3\n>"))
    side4=int(input("Enter side 4\n>"))
    sum=side1+side2+side3+side4
    if (sum %4==0):
        print("Forms a square with perimeter of ",sum)
    elif (sum %2==0):
        print("Forms a rectangle with perimeter of ",sum)
    else:
        print("Does not form a rectangle or square.")

sum_sides ()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the code is a bit redundant. Your function needs arguments (side1,side2,side3,side4). These arguments are passed when you call the function and without them your function doesn't work.

After waiting for the arguments, you reassign the arguments (sides) to 0. So, it doesn't matter if you call the function with the arguments, as you set them as 0 later on.
Then, you ask again for the sides via input.

Also, the "return" must actually return something. It can be a string, a number or a variable, for example.

So, the correct way to do this is:

## 1 (when you don't have the values of the sides yet) - includes the "bonus" of checking if the user input is an integer value. Could be changed to float, if necessary:

```
def sum_sides():
    sidesList = []
    for i in range(4):
        while True:
            side = input(f"Enter side {i+1}: ")
            try:
                int(side)
                sidesList.append(int(side))
                break
            except: print('Please enter a valid number (integer)')
    perimeter = sum(sidesList)

    if (perimeter %4 == 0):
        print("Forms a square with perimeter of ", perimeter)
    elif (perimeter %2 == 0):
        print("Forms a rectangle with perimeter of ", perimeter)
    else:
        print("Does not form a rectangle or square.")

    return perimeter



perimeter = sum_sides()
print(perimeter)
```

## 2 (supposing you already have the values of each side):

```
def sum_sides_2(side1, side2, side3, side4):
    sidesList = [side1, side2, side3, side4]
    perimeter = sum(sidesList)

    if (perimeter %4 == 0):
        print("Forms a square with perimeter of ", perimeter)
    elif (perimeter %2 == 0):
        print("Forms a rectangle with perimeter of ", perimeter)
    else:
        print("Does not form a rectangle or square.")

    return perimeter



perimeter = sum_sides_2(5, 3, 3, 5)
print(perimeter)
```